# Does my miniature giant space piglet do anything?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I pre-ordered the game, and as a result have a miniature giant space piglet. Does it [do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8lLruVR2zQ) anything at all?

Comment: If you name it Boo, you can tell it to go for the eyes.

Comment: @RossRidge Boo says: "Whaaaaaat?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's one of a dozen or so companion pets available in the game. They do nothing other than follow faithfully at your side, looking adorable and/or awesome.

Comment: Beat me to it while I was grabbing a reference. Anyway, here's some support for your answer: https://steamcommunity.com/app/291650/discussions/0/618457398957684695/